# Azure Monitor externaldata operator to query Blob storage using a Private Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks

When writing KQL in an Azure Monitor Workbook and using the [externaldata operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/externaldata-operator?pivots=azuremonitor) to retrieve data from Blob storage is it possible to access the Blob storage through a Private Endpoint?

```
(externaldata (Title:string) [
    @"https://test.blob.core.windows.net/test/todos.json?...SAS.."
] with(format='multijson', ingestionMapping='[{"Column":"Title","Properties":{"Path":"$.title"}}]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

that *specific* behavior/syntax of using KQL + externaldata would be very specific to what you are querying.  It might work if querying an ADX cluster, but might not work for querying log analytics, but really depends on the configuration/settins of the endpoint.

you could also possibly use the "Custom Endpoint" data source in workbooks, though then the auth starts to be the question.

If i use that specific url, `https://test.blob.core.windows.net/test/todos.json` in a custom provider, the *browser* rejects it saying that the blob does not support CORS:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test.blob.core.windows.net/test/todos.json' from origin 'https://ms.portal.azure.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

if the specific url you want to call requires some kind of auth, that gets a little bit harder both from workbook and from the externaldata operator

if you can make a query work in the logs blade or ADX tools with the externaldata syntax, it should also work inside workbooks.

Comment: Thanks. We don't have ADX. We are currently using a "Custom Endpoint" successfully with a SAS. This mostly gives us what we need but has its limitations. I am confused why a "Custom Endpoint" works but externaldata does not. I was hoping querying through a private endpoint would solve the externaldata issue, but since I do not know the underlying issue I'm just hoping it may.

Comment: custom endpoint is a functionality of *workbooks*, in the portal ui, where the portal ui would be calling out to that endpoitn and parsing the results, that code belongs to my team, the workbooks ui team.  externaldata is a feature of the *database you are querying*, so how that works is entirely up to the team that owns the underlying database infrastructure.  the custom endpoint feature of workbooks only works inside workbooks.  the externaldata feature would hypothetically work wherever you can run those queries, in the logs ui, in alerts queries (potentially), etc.